# ASP .Net Core JsonStringEnumConverter Not Serializing Responses

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I want to be able to return enums as their string representations in my Web Api I'm building in .net core 3.1.

I have this in my Startup.cs

`services.AddControllers( ).AddJsonOptions( opts =>{ opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter( JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase)); } );`

This works when sending a request with an enum. The request automatically binds a string in a parameter to match with an enum. However when I return models they are not serialized into their string representation.

This property

`public FunctionStatus Status { get; set; } = FunctionStatus.Canceled;`

is returned in the response json as:

"status": 1

instead of

"status": "canceled"

I do not why it's doing this considering it is working on requests... I cannot find anything relating to this only working on requests to the API and not on responses.

Comment: are you sure your converter works properly? the `model binding` may support parsing for enum value from both number & string. But the other way (returning response) requires a converter. I've just tried a simple demo on my side (targets .net core 2.2) with `Newtonsoft.Json` and it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you show the enum? Do you use the number in enum?

Comment: @Karney.here is the enum public enum FunctionStatus
 {
  Planning,
  Ready,
  Canceled,
 }

Comment: For what it's worth, switching to AddNewtonsoftJson for my services method like @KingKing suggested worked, but I'm not a fan of that since I use System.Text.Json everywhere else in the app and plan to keep it that way. So I would prefer to not mix libraries.

Comment: @JesseR, try to change the configuration `new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,allowIntegerValues:false)` in startup.

Comment: @Karney.adding that bool to the constructor still results in an integer being returned.